# LWC Date should be within 30 Days selected

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

I have written the javascript function for the date should be within the next 30 days. It should not be selected last 30 days and next 30 days on the basis of today's date.

```
handleDateChange(event) {
    const inputDate = new Date(event.target.value);
    const currentDate = new Date();
    const element = this.template.querySelector("[data-name='StartDate']");
    const thirtyDaysFromNow = new Date(currentDate.getTime() + (30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    console.log('Inputdate=====>'+inputDate);
    console.log('thirtyDaysFromNow=====>'+thirtyDaysFromNow);
    
    if (thirtyDaysFromNow > inputDate) {
        // The selected time is less than 30 days from now
        event.target.setCustomValidity("Please select a date within the next 30 days.");
    }
    else if (inputDate < thirtyDaysFromNow) {
        // The selected time is more than 30 days from now
        event.target.setCustomValidity("Please select a date within the next 30 days.");
    }
    else {
        // -Exact- same timestamps.
        event.target.setCustomValidity("");
    }
    
    /*if(inputDate > thirtyDaysFromNow){
        event.target.setCustomValidity("Please select a date within the next 30 days.");
    }else{
        event.target.setCustomValidity("");
    }*/
   
}
```

Comment: And?  Please edit your question with more details about what isn't working, what you've tried, and what error messages you get.  Otherwise this question is likely to be closed.

Comment: @NickCook Original problem is that they check both a < b and a > b, so it will only match on the exact day, not 30 days out, as they desire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually need to use any custom validity. Date fields are perfectly capable of validating a minimum and maximum date automatically.

```
  minDate;
  maxDate;
  connectedCallback() {
    const today = new Date();
    const thirtyDaysLater = new Date();
    thirtyDaysLater.setDate(today.getDate()+30);
    this.minDate = today.toISOString().split('T')[0];
    this.maxDate = thirtyDaysLater.toISOString().split('T')[0];
  }
```

---

```
<lightning-input label="Reservation Date" type="date" min={minDate} max={maxDate}></lightning-input>
```

The input element will automatically report on blur, and will also validate appropriately on `reportValidity()`, `checkValidity()`, and `validity`.

[Demo](https://app.lwc.studio/edit/BJy0HcoZQP2eBuj5apaI/src/child.html?p=stories).

Comment: Can we customize the error message which is coming when we are putting the Date is not in within the mindate and maxdate

Comment: @ShantanuMahajan yes we can set custom message  - using the customValidity method 

 let dateCmp = this.template.querySelector(".dateCls");
dateCmp.setCustomValidity("Date value is required");

Comment: @MukulMahawariya Stop suggesting setCustomValidity, lol. There are standard properties for this, too!

Comment: @ShantanuMahajan You can use the `message-when-range-overflow` and `message-when-range-underflow` properties to customize the message that appears for a too-large or too-small value, respectively.